# Import scripts from multiple urls using one script

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use just one script to import different scripts from different urls? Something like

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

but that works as a script. I want to make something like a library to use on different projects. I don't want to put every scripts in a single file because some of them are developed from other people

Comment: You either append the scripts with JavaScript code or you just bundle the scripts together in one tag.

Comment: Maybe you can accept one of our answers so others can find it too

Comment: @hiru: did one of the below answers help?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as you want it with multiple sources in the `script` tag,
however you could do something like this

```
var srcs=["a/link/to/a/script.js","http://www.and.another/one.js"]
for(var i=0;i<srcs.length;i++){
  var script=document.createElement("script")
  script.src=srcs[i]
  document.head.appendChild(script)
}
```

This will add a script tag in the `head` element based on the content of the srcs variable

Answer (score 1):

```
var head = document.head;
var body = document.body;
function Import( pos, src ) {
    var js = document.createElement('script');
    js.type = 'text/javascript';
    js.setAttribute('src', src);
    pos.appendChild(js);
}
Import( head, 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js');
Import( body, 'http://www.neveldo.fr/mapael/source/js/jquery.mapael.js');
Import( body, 'http://www.neveldo.fr/mapael/source/js/maps/world_countries.js');
Import( head, 'local.js');
```

Comment: Explain what your code does, this is just copy&paste (AKA worthless).